# Can electron gyrating in a magnetic field have discreet energy levels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Take the example of simple cyclotron in which only one electron is gyrating about the center. Can this electron gyrate with arbitrarily small radius(radius is calculated by the speed of it, lower the speed, lower the radius)?
Or does it have a lower limit on radius after which quantum mechanics come into picture and the electron cannot gyrate in a radius lower than that?

Comment: This is exactly the Landau quantization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_quantization